# Chrome Notification/Permission Bar - Detect if visible

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, google-chrome

Chrome displays the following notification bar when flash requests access to the camera or microphone...

[image: Chrome notification bar]

**Is there any JavaScript or AS3 way to be detect if this is/isn't visible?**

Comment: I think you can detect that in Flash itself. Or do you want to know a way to detect it in JavaScript?

Comment: @putvande I'm looking for a way in either language.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's been a long time since you asked, but we finally found a workaround that I would like to share, the ActionScript Camera has a public property called [`currentFPS`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Camera.html#currentFPS) which while the permission is pending will be constant and set to `0`(zero). We use that property to decide either or not we should display a user notification.

Answer (score -1):

Detecting the security bar would be a security breach. I doesn't seem to me that this would be implemented for use in any language.

i am 100% certain this can not be done in javascript as well as AS3

Comment: Why would this be a security breach?

Comment: It would not be a security breach the site/developer know if the permission is pending.