# AS3 - Detect chrome notification bar(allow/deny access to mic/camera)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, google-chrome

Someone already asked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17613571/chrome-notification-permission-bar-detect-if-visible) but no answer yet.

I'd like to detect in chrome(using flash AS3) if the user allowed/denied or did not performed action yet for the allow access notification bar.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Chrome Notification/Permission Bar - Detect if visible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17613571/chrome-notification-permission-bar-detect-if-visible)

Comment: yes, I stated that link in my post :). And there's no answer in that post.